# Keyed shaft is worn down, how do I keep pulley from riding off the end?

Tags: pulley

I have a belt driven pump on a sprayer that is powered by a small engine.  The keyway on the shaft of the pump is a little worn and at some point the key worked itself out.  Unfortunately I did not catch it before the pulley started to wear down the shaft.  I replaced the key with a new one that appears to be snug and tightened down the screw, but the pulley keeps wanting to ride off.
The sprayer is used for fruit trees and I am in the middle of the season, so rebuilding the pump is going to take up precious time.

Is there a way to keep this pulley on the shaft or am I simply out of luck and replacing the shaft is the only route to go?  Would a product like Loctite work (temporarily or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of Band-Aid type options. If the shaft extends past the pulley you could try to add a clamp-tite collar on both sides of the pulley. You can try to drill and tap a second setscrew hole in the pulley. Vibratite makes a retaining product that can be used with clearances up to .0150". Be warned it may be very difficult to remove the pulley without adding some heat. You might wwant to try all three.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately the pulley takes up all of the shaft, so the collar idea is out.  Would you apply the Vibratite on the shaft or just the screw threads?

Comment: To the shaft. The idea is for the Vibratite  to fill in the space between the shaft and the pulley. That reduces the movement that loosens the setscrew. It also has an adhesive quality which is why it can be very difficult to remove later. I would apply regular Loctite to the setscrews.

Comment: Here's the link to the Vibratite Retaining Product http://www.vibra-tite.com/product-items/retaining-compounds/

Comment: Do you think the first one #530 would be sufficient?